# android Layout - scrollview don't show

Tags: android, scrollview

I have a ScrollView which contains EditText, but the problem is it doesn't show properly in the emulator and on a physical device. Can anyone see any problems with my code?

**XML snippet**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:background="@drawable/background2"
tools:context="com.jack.cheng.buddhistcopy.Activity1">
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:isScrollContainer="true"
    android:saveEnabled="true">
    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/sutra"
        android:layout_width="295dp"
        android:layout_height="295dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >
        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <EditText
                android:text="Test"
                android:layout_width="10dp"
                android:layout_height="10dp"
                >
            </EditText>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: what is not shown, the edittext? can you share the xml? hopefully its not the scrollview that you are trying to see..

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding the following attribute to the ScrollView?

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
 <EditText
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="TestText"
      />
```

You might want to use the conditions : `wrap_content`, `fill_parent` or `match_parent` as using these allows your view elements to adjust accordingly to the device screen which can vary.

Also you might want to add an `android:id="@id/myIdentifier"` to that EditText so you can link it to whatever process you have going on in your app.